# How can you replace a new firefox browser with an older one?

Tags: firefox, webbrowser-app

How can you replace a new firefox browser with an older one in the 12.04 ubuntu? Can someone, any one please explain this to a novice that knows nothing about ubuntu? There is no good info here about how to do this. Why is it so hard to get help here? Or with ubuntu all together??

Comment: probably you haven't searched enough before asking the question.

Comment: @VishnuNK I agree. I searched `install old version of firefox ubuntu` and a great deal of good guides came up.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/) are .deb packages for every Firefox version from 3.5 to latest. Install the version of your choice.

Comment: 12.04 is supported, and will be supported until atleast 2017.

Comment: @muru Still, nearly no third-party provides packages for 12.04. While it *is* supported, it is advisable to move to a newer version.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help...I am trying to downgrade to an older version of firefox. The app is in my downloads file now and I can not after SEARCHING for three days and trying to decipher all the info out here and trying everything I can find for explanation, it is not working for me. Nothing works. Is there a simple way to do this like on windows?

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry it is hard for this older person to understand all this...please do not blame me for not understanding all this.

Comment: @Jay Open the file with Software Center and you should be able to install it there.

Comment: OK, thanks and sorry...now my answers are dissappearing? I am older and do not understand all this. Sorry.

Comment: @Jay "my answers are dissappearing" Could you explain, please?

Comment: OK, thanks and sorry... I am older and do not understand all this. Sorry. I do not know what to do when I open the software center. I try to find th e downloaded file, but where is it? Sorry again. I am a total dummy when it comes to anything ubuntu. I barely know windows system too. The deb file is going to my downloads now.

Comment: @Jay It should be in your Downloads folder. If not, check your browser's download history.

Comment: Thank you Bhar, what do i do after it goes to the download file?

Comment: @Jay Open it using Software Center. Then click 'Install'.

Comment: Thank you again...where is it in the software center? I have looked and looked but can not find out where this browser is to open.

Comment: @Jay Right-click deb file and open with Software Center. It will show you a page with the package details - click Install

Comment: THIS...is what I mean by being so confusing. I get help from every written source there is available, but still nothing works. I did what you said with glee that maybe this would work for me. No. I got this: The file “/home/traveler/Downloads/firefox-mozilla-build_27.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb.part” could not be opened. Now what??

Comment: @Jay The .part extension means it was not completely downloaded. So... you'll have to download it again - this is not Software Center's fault, however.

Comment: @Jay Ok - tell me if that worked.

Comment: Very slow to download...sorry...will let you know if this works...thank YOU again...bless.

Comment: 10-15kb a min...very slow service...so sorry...I hope this works...feels like it. Fingers crossedX!

Comment: Downloaded wrong architecture...trying again.

Comment: This is going to take forever here...going to the library! I will thank you and let you know how it went...darn slow Internet!

Comment: This is the unmodified Mozilla release binary of Firefox, packaged into a .deb by the Ubuntuzilla project.

It is strongly recommended that you back up your application profile data before installing, just in case. We really mean it! Ubuntuzilla project homepage:

http://ubuntuzilla.sourceforge.net/ Mozilla project homepage:

http://www.mozilla.comWell...faster downloads of the apps...I get this:hunspel-en-us and:  twice on two different older firefox browsers. it all went well w/ faster downloading, but failed to do what I hoped. Any ideas?

Comment: it is even hard to comment here...like it wants to do it for you?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Well...sorry for asking for help...this was a first time for me...I am not computer savy and I keep running into this exact problem of not being able to get help to do a simple thing that was easy on windows...

Comment: Reckon I'll try somewhere else to get help for ubuntu...thanks to the one person that did reach out to try to help me...I am no where after all day trying to figure this out..how do I reinstall an old version of firefox?

Comment: I have tried everything..I actually used this page and had changed the browser, but now it will not let me do it anymore after shifting back to the newest version, this after turning off the updates too. Why?http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/how-to-install-previous-versions-of-firefox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/ sigh....this is so frustrating...

Comment: @Jay Sorry, timezone difference.